# Fade out audio using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, pannellum

How can I fade out an audio element using vanilla js (no jquery)? I have looked at the numerous other questions on this forum but they all seem overly complicated or use jquery. I have written this code below. However, I get the following error:
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (-7.52870e-16) is outside the range [0, 1]."

```
        viewer.on('mouseup', function(event) {

        var mouseDownSound = document.getElementById("mouseDownSound");
        mouseDownSound.volume = 1;
        var vol = mouseDownSound.volume;
        function fadeOut() { 
            setInterval(
              function() {
                if (vol > 0) {
                  vol -= 0.01;
                  mouseDownSound.volume = vol;
                }
                else {
                  clearInterval(fadeOut);
                }
              }, 2);
        }
        fadeOut();

    });
```

Comment: 200 seconds (-0.01 per 2 secs) are more than 3 minutes, have you waited at least half minute for something to happen?

Comment: thank you, I have made the change, however I have updated the post because now I'm getting an error message: myscript.js:669 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (-7.52870e-16) is outside the range [0, 1].

Comment: Try calling `vol -= 0.01` *before* you test `if(vol > 0)`. That way, if `vol` drops below 0 you won't be attempting to set the volume to an invalid level.

Comment: thank you! it works and doesn't throw an error message. I don't understand why it works though, I would think that the 'vol -= 0.01' would need to be after the test.

Comment: See my answer for a description of why this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `vol` currently has a value of 0.005. The way your code is currently set up, `if (vol > 0)` is `true`, so you will then subtract 0.01, giving `vol` a value of -0.005. Since that is now less than zero, you will get an error when attempting to set the volume to that level.

The fix is to call `vol -= 0.01` *before* you test `if(vol > 0)`. That way, if `vol` drops below 0 you won't be attempting to set the volume to an invalid level.